# user control reflection type is different than class type, causing type equality failure

Tags: c#, reflection, webforms, user-controls

I have a collection of user controls that I want to get out of a screen and do something with. What I've found is that using the `is` keyword when checking the control's type returns `true`, but using `==` returns `false`. E.g.

```
myUserControl is MyUserControl  
true  

myUserControl.GetType() == typeof(MyUserControl)  
false
```

When I inspected the user control using reflection, I found that the user control from the screen has a full name in the format of

```
Project.folder_folder_control_ascx
```

whereas the class of the user control is

```
Project.folder.folder.control
```

But none of the .NET controls work this way. Their `GetType().FullName` is the regular class namespace.
To get the dot format, you have to go to the base type:

```
myUserControl.GetType().BaseType == typeof(MyControl)  
true
```

I was able to get the controls that I needed by using `is` for each type I wanted, rather than putting all of the types in a list. Is there a resolution for this situation, since you can't do

```
controls.Where(control => validTypes.Any(vt => control is vt))
```

I'm guessing the reasoning has to do with UserControls being partial classes and whatnot, but I'm not sure what's happening or why or if there's a way to get `GetType() == typeof(t)` to return `true`.

Comment: Does `myUserControl.GetType().Equals(typeof(MyUserControl))` also return false ?

Comment: @Mat Yes, using .Equals also returns false